# Server 2008 R2Crashes

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, bsod, windows-server-2008

We're running a setup as follows using Hyper-V:

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 (Hyper-V Host)
   |
   |-- SBS 2008 (DC)
   |__ Windows Server 2008 R2 (TS)
```

Recently we've experienced multiple crashes that we cannot pin down. When we look at the server (after the network connections go down) the monitor we attached to the host 2008 install is blank and will not respond. A restart will bring the servers back up, but the "unexpected shutdown" dialog box reports a bluescreen with minimal detail:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID: 2057

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode: 101
  BCP1: 0000000000000019
  BCP2: 0000000000000000
  BCP3: FFFFF88001E5D180
  BCP4: 0000000000000002
  OS Version: 6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product: 272_3
```

Anecdotally, removing the Kyocera printer drivers from the SBS VM seemed to stop crashes (we were experiencing two a day at this point). We have now, however, had a further event today - even though the printer drivers are now on a seperate machine entirely.

Any ideas?!

EDIT: As an aside; we can't see any relevant errors in the Event Viewer that would explain this.

Comment: Check whether the C2 states are enabled in the BIOS, if they are, disable them. We had some problems with C2 states in Hyper-V R2.

Comment: When you say that you removed the Kyocera printer drivers, did you just delete the printer or did you remove the drivers from the print server properties drivers tab?

Comment: I deleted the driver from the Print Management console (actually remove the driver, not just the entry). Not lookin at the C2 states, I'll check it thanks.

Comment: here is an important link for hyper-v r2 hotfixes  "http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394763(WS.10).aspx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STOP 101 is CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT, it's a MB, CPU, and/or Onboard Management Chip problem. Check if there is updated BIOS/Firmware and Driver for any of those. We had a problem with this in a particular line of servers and it turned out to be a Firware issue.

Comment: Many thanks; this ties in with a hotfix we found for our hardware setup. Good shout ;)